# Why is the list NULL?

Tags: c

Why is the list NULL?

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int elem;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct Node* List;

List empty()
{
    List l = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    return l;
}

void addl(List l, int e)
{
    Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->elem = e;
    n->next = l;
    l = n;
}

int main()
{
    List l = empty();

    addl(l, 1);
    addl(l, 2);

    if (l == NULL)
    {
        printf("IS NULL");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

return → IS NULL

why ? Why not addr to the list?

Comment: Hola amigo, deberias publicar el titulo en Ingles para que la mayoria entienda tu pregunta. Asi es mas probable que consigas mas ayuda.

Comment: Please stick to English or use https://es.stackoverflow.com/ https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Don't hide pointer types behind typedefs like in `typedef struct Node* List;`, it's bad practice and it only causes confusion.

Comment: `l = n;` in `addl()` does not change the `l` in `main()`.

Comment: `typedef struct Node {  int elem; List next; } Node;` is not valid C code. "error: unknown type name 'List'".  Joaquin Garcia, What compiler are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

I have made improvemnts and fixed some parts of your code. Compare it with yours and find your mistakes.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Node
{
    int elem;
    struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct Node *List;

List newList(int e)
{
    List l = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (l == NULL)
    {
        printf("IS NULL");
        return NULL;
    }
    l->elem = e;
    l->next = NULL;
    return l;
}

void addl(List l, int e)
{
    List n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(n == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation error");
    }
    printf("New node: %p\n", n);
    n->next = NULL;
    n->elem = e;

    List iter = l;
    if(iter->next == NULL) {
        // If there is only one node (head) in the node add the new one to the next
        iter->next = n;
    }
    else {
        while(iter->next) {
            // Iterate until find the last node
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        iter->next = n; // Finally add the new node to the end of the list
    }
}

int main()
{
    List l = newList(0);

    addl(l, 1);
    addl(l, 2);

    List iterate = l;
    int i = 1;
    do {
        printf("%d. node's element is %d\n", i, iterate->elem);
        iterate = iterate->next;
        i++;
        if(iterate->next == NULL) {
            // Catch the last node
            printf("%d. node's element is %d\n", i, iterate->elem);
        }
    }
    while(iterate->next);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code:

```
New node: 0x8292c0
New node: 0x8296f0
1. node's element is 0
2. node's element is 1
3. node's element is 2
```

Comment: Consider `List l = malloc(sizeof *l);`.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: How do you suggest to form an empty list such that `l` has zero items?

Comment: How about pointing out the changes, and **why** you made them.

Comment: @Kozmotronik That's not how SO works. If your answer isn't complete, people will downvote it, regardless of whether they have answered themselves.